# What causes a method to be classed as "'not compilable (disabled)" by the hotspot compiler?

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

After making some changes to an application it suffered a significant performance degradation and on investigation one of the most frequently called methods is no longer being compiled.  Turning on: `-XX:+LogCompilation` shows that before the change, this method was: queued for compilation, compiled, and then successfully inlined into callers; whereas after the change, there is no record of a compilation attempt and the inlining attempt says:

> inline_fail reason='not compilable (disabled)'

The original method is as follows, where `_maxRepeats` is an instance variable declared as a `Map` (no generics, code written a long time ago), used such that the key was an object of class `DadNode` and the value was an `Integer`.

```
  private int cnsGetMaxRepeats(DadNode dn) {
    if (_maxRepeats != null) {
      Integer max = (Integer)_maxRepeats.get(dn);
      if (max != null) {
        return max;
      }
    }
    return dn.getMaxOccurs().getValue();
  }
```

The amendment involved changing the `_maxRepeats` map to use generics:

```
  Map<Integer, Integer>
```

and a new parameter was added to the method:

```
   private int cnsGetMaxRepeats(int childIdx, DadNode dn) {
    if (_maxRepeats != null) {
      Integer max = _maxRepeats.get(childIdx);
      if (max != null) {
        return max;
      }
    }
    return dn.getMaxOccurs().getValue();
  }
```

Using explicit calls to `Integer.valueOf` and `Integer.intValue` to avoid autoboxing make no difference; the method is still not compilable.

I can "poke it with a stick" until I get a solution which does what I want (and is also compilable), but what are the criteria behind this disabling?

Comment: It may be marked un-complilable for reasons unrelated to the code itself. For example, have you tried increasing code cache size?  `-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize`

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Is the OS 32-bit or 64-bit? Are you using the client compiler or the server compiler?

Comment: what version are you using? `LogCompilation` is `PrintCompilation` for a long time...

Answer (score 2):

I think a basic mistake on my part - the log with the "compilation disabled" method was produced when running debug through IntelliJ (although with breakpoints muted).  I expect IntelliJ disables compilations for methods with breakpoints in, even when muted.

So to answer my own question, I have no reason to think that anything apart from explicitly disabling compilation will do so.